# Trouble with undefined reference to Callstack library

Tags: android, c++, c, callstack

I try to build a `cpp` file as below to an executable on the Android platform. Therefore, by calling dumping_callstack(), I can get call stack of my executable in run time. But there are some errors。

1. cpp file:mycallstack.cpp

   ```
   #include <utils/CallStack.h>
   extern "C" void dumping_callstack()
   {
        CallStack stack("haha");
   }
   ```
2. mycallstack.h

   ```
   void dumping_callstack();
   ```
3. test.c

   ```
   #include <mycallstack.h>

   main()
   {
      dumping_callstack();
   }
   ```
4. android.mk

   ```
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES += mycallstack.cpp
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc libcutils liblog libutils
   ```

then compile.

```
error: undefined reference to 'android::CallStack::CallStack(char const*,int)'
error: undefined reference to 'android::CallStack::~CallStack()'
```

Answer (score 4):

In android 9.0, you should use `libutilscallstack`.
Look "android/system/core/libutils/Android.bp" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `CallStack::CallStack` and `CallStack::~CallStack` isn't provided to the compiler/linker.
You might forgot to link it to the corresponding object file/library, I suggest you to read the documentation, there might be some information about linking. Sometimes it can help to just compile it with the `-static` switch, this makes the executable almost standalone, some libraries even require to be linked staticly.

It might also be the case, that the implementation is not available for release builds, I think the `CallStack`-class could only be available for debugging.